# Pig script to concatenate the values in the tuples

Tags: apache-pig

Input:

```html
(11111111,{(A,MARK,APPLE,ABC1,11111111),(B,PAUL,AMAZON,ABC2,11111111),(C,TIM,FIVN,ABC3,11111111),(D,LIN,MULESFT,ABC4,11111111),(E,YEP,UHG,ABC5,11111111),(F,QIN,ATT,ABC6,11111111)})
(22222222,{(A,MARK,APPLE,ABC6,22222222),(B,MARK,AMAZON,ABC7,22222222),(C,MARK,PQE,ABC8,22222222),(D,MARK,AMB,ABC9,22222222),(E,MARK,YZQ,ABC19,22222222),(F,MARK,PQR,,22222222)})
```

I have grouped the data with the key as above. I should generate the output by concatenating all the values of the tuple including nulls as below:

Output:

```html
(1111111,A^B^C^D^E^F,MARK^PAUL^TIM^LIN^YEP^QIN,APPLE^AMAZON^FIVN^MULESFT^UHG^ATT,ABC1^ABC2^ABC3^ABC4^ABC5^^ABC6)
(2222222,A^B^^D^E^G,TIM^AIN^TIM^BIN^CIN^DIN^RIN,APPLE^AMAZON^PQE^AMB^YZQ^RIN,ABC6^ABC7^ABC8^ABC9^ABC19^^)
```

Can some one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a code snippet which may help, work on this to achieve the expected output.

**Input :**

```
1,A
1,B
1,C
2,D
2,E
2,F
```

**Output :**

```
(1,C^B^A)
(2,F^E^D)
```

**Pig Snippet :**

```
data1 = load '/Users/muralirao/learning/pig/a.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray);
req_data = FOREACH (GROUP data1 BY id) { 
    names = data1.name;
    GENERATE group AS id, BagToString(names,'^');  
};

DUMP req_data;
```

Comment: you can think of accepting this as answer if it helped.